# Authorize Attribute to Domain Group is Prompting for Credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using the Authorize attribute I can do domain\username fine. IIS does the windows authentication. However if I try to do authorize to a domain group, I am prompted for authentication. Is there something I am missing?

Code is basically this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "NMBS\\CapacityRead")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

IIS has Windows authentication enabled. All other forms are disabled.

This is is auth portion of my web.config. If this is not defining the provider, I assume that I am using whatever is default.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Please Share your code snippet. Also, what membership/role provider are you using? How is IIS configured for authentication?